# How to check if route is in transition

Tags: ember.js

Is there any way to check if a route is in transition? I need to add a loading state to a view while the model is being fetched.

I've found several different answers but none seem to work. Wondering if there's a canonical/idiomatic approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a look in that [gist](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589), it have some usefull information about how to create a global loading, or just for one route

Comment: Yes, the model hook expect a object that return a promise, in other words, return a object that have a method called then. And the return from App.Person.find(), return it.

Comment: hmm, only works on the initial load. I transition using `transitionTo` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with this problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot - I've asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837128/what-controls-where-embers-loading-route-is-displayed

Comment: I have aswered the other question. Please give a look.